# How to Plot modulo function Mod on a function of two variables?

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions, modular-arithmetic

I know that `Plot[Mod[x, 2], {x, -6, 6}]` is a Mathematica command to plot the remainder of x over 2 when I range x over reals -6 to 6. How do I plot the same `Mod` function on a real valued two variable function f(x,y) in the following manner?

```
Plot[Mod[f(x,y), 2], {x, -6, 6}, {y, -6, 6}]
```

More details, if needed: This is my exact function f(t,c) = (t/2)*Log[c^2 + 1] + (k/2 - 0.1) Arg[1/(c - I)] where I am varying k as a parameter as shown below.

```
Manipulate[ Plot[Mod[(t/2)*Log[c^2 + 1] + (k/2 - 0.1) Arg[1/(c - I)], 2 Pi], {t, 2 Pi, 4 Pi}, {c, -100, -4}, PlotRange -> {0, 10}, ClippingStyle -> None], {k, 12, 300}]
```

Above here is the actual code that I am using.
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `Plot` to `Plot3D`:

```
Manipulate[
Plot3D[Mod[(t/2)*Log[c^2 + 1] + (k/2 - 0.1) Arg[1/(c -I)], 2 Pi], {t, 2 Pi, 4 Pi}, {c, -100, -4}, PlotRange ->{0, 10},ClippingStyle -> None]
, {k, 12, 300}]
```

[image]